# Why ReactJs Error Boundaries are not triggered on event handlers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I'm wondering why we can't use the same error handling technique for event handlers than for the rest of the React's lifecycle methods.

Reacts provide an answer to it , but still I have my concerns.

> Error boundaries do not catch errors inside event handlers.
>
> React doesn't need error boundaries to recover from errors in event
>   handlers. Unlike the render method and lifecycle hooks, the event
>   handlers don't happen during rendering. So if they throw, React still
>   knows what to display on the screen.
>
> If you need to catch an error inside event handler, use the regular
>   JavaScript try / catch statement:

I think allowing us to have the same behavior on error handling would provide us a uniform way to display them to the User, even if they are not happening at the render time an error on an event handler may block User interactions on the UI.

We could use try/catch for handling those exceptions , but then we will need to create a new way to handle the display of those errors.

in conclusion I would like to know the the main motivation to exclude error handlers from error boundaries.

Thanks!

Comment: i have done the same question on react  :https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11409 and they pointed out the documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#how-about-event-handlers , while this doesn't answer my question , digging a bit more on how React fiber works make me guess that react doesn't really know what is happening on the event handlers during the render lifecycles , though can't catch the exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Refer the tricks that mentioned in the following link
https://jaketrent.com/post/react-error-boundaries-event-handlers/

Setting up State will trigger Render event which will fire the componentDidCatch event. Hope this answer your questions.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    try {
      // something that produces an error
    } catch(err) {
      this.setState(() => { throw err; })
    }
  }
}
```